# Vertically center inside a `flex-grow: 1`

Tags: css, flexbox

say I have HTML as

```
<div class="page">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="foo">
      <div>I want to be center of content</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.page {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.header {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background-color: green;
  height: 50px;
}
.content {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.footer {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background-color: steelblue;
  height: 150px;
}

.foo {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

https://codepen.io/rrag/pen/PRmOYe

I achieved a sticky footer at the bottom of the page
using `flex-grow` but that leads to a content with unknown height

How do I center something in the middle of `content`?
Is it possible using flexbox or may be an alternative approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have almost the exact right idea! Instead of setting your vertical centering rules on `.foo` (`display: flex;`, `justify-content: center`; and `align-items: center;`), you instead simply need to set them on the parent `.content`.

This can be seen in the following (Click `Run snippet` and then`Full page` to see this in effect):

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.page {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background-color: green;
  height: 50px;
}

.content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.footer {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background-color: steelblue;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="foo">
      <div>I want to be center of content</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

This can also be seen **[on CodePen](https://codepen.io/Obsidian-Age/pen/bvWYpO)**.

Comment: Great answer, Thanks a lot

Comment: Hi @Obsidian Age a follow up question, once I do that it does not fit the contents inside - https://codepen.io/rrag/pen/eMWxqO remove 3 div.box and I get the center, but with more content it does not grow to fit

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer your follow up question in comments:
You can wrap your content between two flex spacers:

HTML:

```
<div class="page">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="vertical-spacer"></div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="vertical-spacer"></div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.page {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

  .header {
    //...
  }

  .vertical-spacer {
    flex: 1;
  }

  .wrapper {
    //...
  }

  .footer {
    //...
  }
}
```

Here it is in CodePen: https://codepen.io/glf86/pen/rNqPJqw